# Regex with multiple lines

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

So I am trying to process the following text. What I want is to get a match for the data starting with the credits for each class and ending it with the season and year. So for the first class it would look like this:

```
3 credits in Philosophical Perspectives
PHIL 101L
PHILOSOPHICAL PERSPECTIVES
B
3
Fall 2014
```

Also I need to get the classes they still need as well. If you notice they are missing 3 credits in history. Here is my text:

```
3 credits in Philosophical Perspectives
PHIL 101L
PHILOSOPHICAL PERSPECTIVES
B
3
Fall 2014
Student View
3 credits in Fine Arts
ART 160L
HIST WEST ART I
B+
3
Fall 2014
3 credits in History
Still Needed:
Click here to see classes that satisfy this requirement.
3 credits in Literature
ENG 201L
INTRO LINGUISTIC
IP
(3)
Spring 2016
3 credits in Math
Still Needed:
Click here to see classes that satisfy this requirement.
3 credits in Natural Science
BIOL 225L
TOPICS IN NUTRITION
A-
3
Spring 2015
3 credits Ethics/Applied Ethics/Religious Studies
REST 209L
WORLD RELIGIONS
A-
3
Spring 2015
3 credits in Social Science
ECON 104L
PRINC MACROECONOM
T
3
Fall 2014
```

Comment: And what have you tried? There is a multi-line modifier for regex

Comment: I only could get this far. (\d credits)(.*)(?=\n). Which only grabs the first line. I am pretty new to regex and have not really got a good handle on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?:^|(?<=\n))\d+\s+credits[]\s\S]*?(?=\n\d+\s+credits|$)
```

You can use this with `findall`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/gK9aI6/1

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?:^|(?<=\n))\d+\s+credits[]\s\S]*?(?=\n\d+\s+credits|$)')
test_str = "3 credits in Philosophical Perspectives\nPHIL 101L\nPHILOSOPHICAL PERSPECTIVES\nB\n3\nFall 2014\nStudent View\n3 credits in Fine Arts\nART 160L\nHIST WEST ART I\nB+\n3\nFall 2014\n3 credits in History\nStill Needed:\nClick here to see classes that satisfy this requirement.\n3 credits in Literature\nENG 201L\nINTRO LINGUISTIC\nIP\n(3)\nSpring 2016\n3 credits in Math\nStill Needed:\nClick here to see classes that satisfy this requirement.\n3 credits in Natural Science\nBIOL 225L\nTOPICS IN NUTRITION\nA-\n3\nSpring 2015\n3 credits Ethics/Applied Ethics/Religious Studies\nREST 209L\nWORLD RELIGIONS\nA-\n3\nSpring 2015\n3 credits in Social Science\nECON 104L\nPRINC MACROECONOM\nT\n3\nFall 2014"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Comment: Thanks this answer works the best!

Answer (score 0):

You can combine a non-greedy "anything" sequence and use the known structure of the last line of each set to parse them into chunks:

```
/((?:.\n?)*?(?:Fall|Summer|Spring|Winter)\s\d{4})/g
```

1. `(?:.\n?)*?` - eat any character (possibly with a newline after it) *one a time*
2. then simply match the end sequence: `(?:Fall|Summer|Spring|Winter)\s\d{4}`

[See the demo here](https://regex101.com/r/nB9wC7/2) and note that each credit is in fact single regex match.

Answer (score 0):

Try following snippet:

```
import re

courses = r"....your...content"

rx = re.compile(r"\d+.*?(?:FALL|SPRING)\s*\d{4}", re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
for course in rx.finditer(courses):
    print(course.group())
    print("----------------------------\n")
```

if `courses` contains your sample content, output will be:

```
3 credits in Philosophical Perspectives
PHIL 101L
PHILOSOPHICAL PERSPECTIVES
B
3
Fall 2014
----------------------------

3 credits in Fine Arts
ART 160L
HIST WEST ART I
B+
3
Fall 2014
----------------------------

3 credits in History
Still Needed:
Click here to see classes that satisfy this requirement.
3 credits in Literature
ENG 201L
INTRO LINGUISTIC
IP
(3)
Spring 2016
----------------------------

... omitting rest....
```